# Multiple table data within same form

Tags: php, sql

I have a table called invoice_details consisting of :
id
invoice_id
product_id
product_name
quantity
price

I have a form field that allows input of the product name,qty,etc.
I want to add a column that will be called "room".  The script I have now auto generates more form fields as I need them, in which I could add "room" and specify within the form field, but I want to have the following workflow :

1. Page loads Rooms(or lack of)
2. click a button to add a room(or
      multiples)
3. ability to search products, and click and drag products
       to specific rooms
4. have all data saved correspondingly in sql
       database

What web technologies do I need to research to be able to achieve the above result?

Comment: You already listed them in your tags. Maybe +javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. JavaScript/jQuery to handle the front end clicking dragging
2. PHP (I assume you're already using it) to handle the database queries
3. PDO - a function in PHP for writing to databases
4. AJAX - a way of getting data from your JavaScript front end to the PHP backend

Incidentally - you might want to look at [InteractJS](http://interactjs.io/) which is designed to handle the drag and drop your're looking for - you just have to then AJAX the data back to your PHP server for processing.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I know I didn't explain very well, but you dialed into exactly what I was looking for

Comment: No problem - glad I could help @Steven